# How to switch between PHP Classes?

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop

I am currently developing a web app which has following three classes. (One is parent and other two are child classes.)

```
class Members {} /* Parent Class */

class Group1 extends Members {} /* Child class 1 */

class Group2 extends Members {} /* Child class 2 */
```

The requirement is quite simple. All persons in Group 1 or Group 2 **Must be a Member.** But my question is, what should I do if a person in Group 1 decided to move Group 2? Creating a new group 2 object will remove all the past data. But **Everything he/she has done in Group 1 must be preserved.** Any help how to do this in **Proper Way** is highly welcome..!

Comment: what have you tried ? at least put a bit of research or show it before asking a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seams like you misuse the inheritance. I assume, that you need to have only 2 classes: Member class an Group class.

You need to create 2 instances of Group class an create the reference class field in member class.

You'll have the following advantages:

- Group and members information is divided.
- You can have as many groups as you want
- Moving to another group is as simple as changing the value of reference field.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex..!! You saved my days..! If u can, please post the code. I am still new to PHP OOP and it would be a great help.